# Loading a Google Chart via Ajax

Tags: ajax, charts, google-visualization

I've put together a simple expenses tracking page and I'm currently trying to load a Google chart using .load() - however when I load my page I receive this error:

```
google is not defined
function drawChart() {
```

https://www.google.com/jsapi is called within my chart script and works on its own but fails when loading via Ajax.

Here's what I use to call the chart..

```
$("#divRight").load("chart.pl?dtfm=" + dtfm + "&dtto=" + dtto);
```

Many thanks.

-- Code --

Snippet from chart.pl

Total: £19.15

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Description');
data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
data.addRows([
    ['Groceries', 7.16],
    ['Web / Hosting', 5.99],
    ['Miscellanious', 4.00],
    ['Breakfast', 2.00]

]);
var options = {
    title: ''
};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style='height:400px; width:400px; cursor:pointer;'></div>
```

Snippet from index.pl

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#divRight").load("chart.pl?dtfm=" + dtfm + "&dtto=" + dtto);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you include Google JSAPI script before the load and callback methods ?

Here is the code if you didn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: Hi ChapMic. The Google JSAPI is included in my chart.pl script (this scripts grabs some data from a database between dates from and to (defined in the URL) and then spits out a chart.

If I run the chart script on its own I can return a chart - but via Ajax it comes up with the error.

I've tried adding the Google JSAPI script in both pages - however it  tries to forward me to google.com and brings up a blank page which eventually times out.

I imagine it's probably something daft that I have missed - however after searching the web - I haven't yet found a solution to my problem!

Comment: Could you give us some code ? Maybe we will find it faster by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Google may have a cross domain policy ?